# Django get url path without using "request.path"

Tags: python, django, url, path, http-status-code-404

I am creating a 404.html page in django which will be called when i raise "Http404"

I dont know if 404.html will be passed a "RequestContext" object but can I generate the requested url path without using request variable

I tried "request.path" and "request.get_full_path" but they dont work for me.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The 404 template *will* be rendered with a request context (unlike the 500 server error template).

Make sure that the [`django.core.context_processors.request`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#django-core-context-processors-request) context processor is in your `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` setting. Note that it is not included by default.

Once you've done that, the [request methods](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#methods) that you mention like `get_full_path` should work.