# Django Grabbing Value field from POST

Tags: django

I have an app that let users create blogs and allow other users to comment on each other blogs.The Problem is .In order to create a comment object , I require the blog id and text . I can grab the text data via post but I'm having trouble getting the blog id from POST  and the only way I can think of getting it is via value field in the form

How can I grab the value field from POST?

My models

```
class Blog(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    description = models.TextField()



class BlogComment(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    body = models.TextField()
    blog = models.ForeignKey(Blog)
```

my forms.py

```
class BlogCommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
        text = forms.CharField(required=False)
        class Meta:
                model = BlogComment
                fields = ()



<form method ="POST"> {% csrf_token %}

    <input type = "hidden" name="d" value= "blog.id" />

{{form}}
</form>
```

My views

```
def Blogs(request,blog_id):
        form = BlogCommentForm(request.POST)

        if request.method == "POST":
            if form.is_valid():

                text = form.cleaned_data['text']
                value = form.cleaned_data['value']

       form = BlogCommentForm()
       blog.objects.get(pk=blog_id)

    comment = BlogComment.objects.filter(blog=blog)

return render(request,'blogcomment.html',{'comment':comment,'form':form})
```

Comment: You need some curly braces there `value="{{ blog.id }}"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
request.POST['d']
```

or to avoid raising an `Exception` if it's not there use

```
request.POST.get('d', False)
```

Comment: request.POST is like a python dictionary, you get the value using the name.

Comment: Also, see my comment about the missing curly braces in your template.

Comment: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'fifth' I'm getting this error . What should I do?

Comment: b = request.POST['d']                                                 blog= Blog.objects.get(pk=b)

Answer (score 1):

You can always get the blog id from ?= parameter in url.
When user goes to comment someone's blog the url might be http://yoursite.com/blog/id/comment or http://yoursite.com/blog/comment?blogid=12345.

Comment: Ok , How do I get the URL?

Comment: you can get the url using request.path but why are making this so complicated for your self use django comments and create a reference for your blogs in django comments

Comment: @dusual well , i made the comment feature already , it's simple but I just don't know how to get the id .can you give me an example on how i can use request.path to get the url? into my views

Comment: Ok, in Django if you have url like: url/blog/id you can have:
in urls.py:
url(r'^blog/(\d{1,11})',blog) - where blog is the name of the view, the second part is allowing the url to open the view with string of up to 11 numbers (only numbers) as ID.

In views:

def blog(request, blog_id):
...

The second parameter is the ID you want to put in the path and redirect to it. It is always easy to get this, because this is the view parameter.

When it comes to ?blogid=1234 you can try:
blog_id = request.args.get('blogid')

Comment: @jacob you should check this page out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10037200/django-get-url-path-without-using-request-path